# Issue with PUT request in node js

Tags: node.js, rest

I have below code which is working fine for GET and POST but not for PUT in node js. I am using method overloading for GET and PUT.

````
const AuthRoutes = Router();
const AppRoutes = Router();
AuthRoutes.get('/customer/:customername', getCustomerbyname);
AuthRoutes.post('/calculate/:id', calculate);
AuthRoutes.put('/customer/:customername', saveCustomer);```
````

Here my GET and POST is working fine but for PUT its giving me error. Below URL I am trying for PUT.

> https://domainname/customer/abc

I dont know what I am missing here.

> Error -   You don't have permission to access /domainname/customer/abc

Can you please help me if I am missing something here. Basically I am trying to do a PUT request by providing customer name in URL and other details in BODY section of request. So if customer with name exist, it will update it otherwise create it newly. Am I missing any npm package here?

Comment: Even if now I have changed PUT url to saveCustomer but still same error.

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: @FernandoRamirez yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
       res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS');
          next();
    });
```

I took it from here :
[Response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463740/9339135)