# Express.js CORS configuration, PUT does not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, cors

I have a React application and Nodejs(Express) in the Backend. After deploying to the host server, The function I did for updating some documents stop working properly. It gives the CORS error:

[image]

I have this line of code to handle CORS policy in my server.js:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.set({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
           "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE", 
           "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With"})
  next();
});
```

It is ok for GET and POST methods but does not work for PUT (Don't know if Delete works haven't tried)

I am on this issue for plenty of time; tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463858/11896129

looked for a bunch of solutions on the net, tried to configure it from IIS web.config file, nothing resolve my problem. Which part may I miss?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my)

Comment: Have you tried using the `cors` nodeJS module? It might do the job for you.

Comment: I did it also. I am now trying to configure from its npm page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors but still no result

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker  https://i.hizliresim.com/Am1zzU.png

Comment: @sideshowbarker When I click it, it gives my "failed token" message, which I configured in my auth.js middleware in the backend, it simply checks if the user logged in, before changing a post

Comment: _I have a React application and Nodejs(Express) in the Backend_ - The best way to solve the CORS problem is to eliminate it by serving React script bundles from the backend server. See [this](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/) project (I'm the author) and search README for _CORS_.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look but didn't understand exactly. Is it a server-side rendering app like Next.js?

Comment: Currently there is no SSR. Coming back to CORS, the result of the React application build are files: `.html` pages, `.js` script bundles with React code and optionally `.map` files. All these files are called build artifacts. If you make Express serve the build artifacts then client's browser gets everything (build artifacts and API responses) from the single backend server. This leaves to room for CORS. So there is no need for CORS headers and packages that send these headers.

Comment: hmm, But why this CORs config I made doesn't work? I mean I am executing all the details, OPTIONS, preflight, etc. what is the problem right now, right here ?

Comment: Try disabling all your extensions, and/or try in an Incognito window. And try clearing the cookies and your browser cache for the site. And disable any anti-virus software you have installed. And try from a different browser, and from a different machine, and from a different network. The point being to eliminate the possibility that some other software running or your machine might be interfering with the request, and eliminate the possibility that some firewall setting is interfering with, etc.

Comment: _what is the problem right now, right here_ You got a very reasonable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60631328/12005425). It tells you (along with the supplied links) that `PUT` requires a preflight request. The error screenshot you provided suggests that either (a) this request is not sent or (b) the response is not received from   `reactback.2ccrm.org` or (c) this response is received and contains a rejection/error or (d) this response is received without the HTTP header your red error message complains about as being not present. So I'd suggest start looking at (a)-(d) using DevTools.

Comment: @OnerT. how do you serve your application to the server? Apache or Nginx proxy? Maybe the proxy server blocks CORS related requests.

Comment: @ChristosLytras it is Plesk Obsidian for Windows

Comment: @OnerT. if the issue only occurs in the `localhost`, download a browser plugin called `Cors Everywhere` . that shoudl solve it right away

Answer (score 5):

As stated on [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

> Additionally, for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on server's data (in particular, for HTTP methods **other than GET, or for POST usage with certain MIME types**), the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method.

So you do have to answer preflight requests:

```
  app.options("*", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Preflight request allowed");
  });
```

Read more about preflight requests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381105/cors-what-is-the-motivation-behind-introducing-preflight-requests).

Comment: @Jonas Does [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package add `options` by default? Because I have an express server that serves a `PUT` request and I don't add any `options` handling just the `cors` package.

Comment: @ChristosLytras yes, it does, as you can see [in the sourcecode](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/c3c262bae2fa9ef0b1fbdad2f6cb922f78cfaa40/lib/index.js#L180)

Comment: Can you show the order of your registration of your middlewares for your `express` server? These options and the `CORs` headers that you are using look good.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, I used this CORS configuration

```
  app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

    next();
  });
```

Comment: Nope, not working. I 've tried lots of variations of these, no use

Comment: do you test with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"

Comment: yep, I did it also. It is ok for POST and GET, PUT doesn't work

Comment: are you using Nginx ? if yes then use this configurations as well .

Comment: Nginx  `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";`

Comment: share your request code here as well , as get and post is working as they are only using in login and register before session but put is using after login in session so error is only due to Authorization header

Comment: please remove all cors settings and i updated new code use this as app middleware before routes

Comment: `app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    
    next();
  });`

Comment: sorry not working, I think the problem is different, I will reset all stuff and try again

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` that you see is coming from the preflight OPTIONS request, which is *most likely* not even reaching your express backend but is being hanlded by webserver in the front.

Either arrange for OPTIONS requests also to be relayed to your express backend in your webserver configuration or instruct the webserver to respond to it with required headers.

Check these:

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001338265-How-to-set-up-CORS-cross-origin-resource-sharing-in-Plesk-for-Linux-

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005431913-Is-it-possible-to-enable-CORS-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-Plesk-for-Windows

https://talk.plesk.com/threads/iis-cors-configuration-problem-for-node-js-backend.355677/

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm package cors (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) in your project. Install it and then configure it as a middleware. And put it before your application routes.

```
 const cors = require("cors");

    const corsOptions = {   origin: "*",   methods:
    "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",   allowedHeaders:
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Origin,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-Token,X-Refresh-Token",   credentials: true,   preflightContinue: false,  
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204 };

    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Brother Oner, I am using the same in my project and it's working.

Comment: I understand but it is not working in mine. I tried lots of variants of these cors package, also did it with manually setting headers etc. There should be another way,  because, in the backend, I have routes and auth middleware like any other usual app, nothing exceptional but still doesn't work. I can share whole app.js and routes also

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below configuration

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors())
```

Please let me know if works for you or not.

See the Github repo for more info: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Answer (score 0):

We can use npm package to enable this too

```
npm install --save cors
```

After package is in place, use it as middleware as follows.

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

If you have requirement to confine your resource access to single application, that can be done as following

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://yourapp.com'
}));
```

If you have requirement to add access to multiple applications, that can be done as follows

```
var allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000',
                      'http://yourapp.com'];
app.use(cors({
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    // allow requests with no origin 
    // (like mobile apps or curl requests)
    if(!origin) return callback(null, true);
    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1){
      var msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not ' +
                'allow access from the specified Origin.';
      return callback(new Error(msg), false);
    }
    return callback(null, true);
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you write middleware that attaches header before the line of code that handles PUT request? I have a similar code but it worked for me.
Another approach is to use npm 'cors' module.

For testing purpose, you can attach below test (you can attach the specific headers/methods later):

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
```